# How to inherit Fragment and AppCompatActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, inheritance, fragment

Viewpager is not working it shows error. Please help me.
And I have one more doubt, how extend Fragments and AppCompatActivity  in same class. I do know that java does not support multiple inheritance but is there any way to implement it?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager;
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new                 ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "FRAG1");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentTwo(), "FRAG2");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentThree(), "FRAG3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) MainActivity.this);



    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fragment One", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }




    };



class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
    }
}
```

The code for fragment one, fragment two and fragment three are similar here is the Code  :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

public FragmentOne() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
}

}
```

Comment: Please show us what's the issue you are receiving

Comment: I have the impression you messed up with your closing brackets `}`.
Control that classes are closed before a new one is opened and check that only one closing bracket for a class is applied (functions still be closed additionally).

Comment: complier shows that class cannot extend multiple class

Comment: Diamond inheritance (i.e. inheriting from multiple classes) is not supported in Java.